# Smashed chain link fence?

Tags: fence

People have been using my back yard as a walk way for sometime. I recently bought the house and my dog goes berserk every time they come through. The fence is smashed beyond anything I have seen on the internet. What can I use to re-stretch the fence back to normal?

Comment: Can you show us a picture?  I have some amateur ideas and I'm sure others have better ideas, but it would help if we knew where we were re-stretching it to, if it has a tension wire at the base, etc.

Comment: You'd typically use a fence stretcher: http://www.homedepot.com/p/YARDGARD-36-in-Galvanized-Steel-Hook-Stretcher-Bar-with-3-Hooks-328753DPT/202025423 ...but note that chain link fences are fairly easy to climb. Might be better off planting thorn bushes/blackberries/etc.

Comment: Chain link fences are fairly simple to work on, just need to know a trick or two. Depending on how the fence is constructed, no special tools are needed, short of wire cutters and a way to cut hollow pipe, if needed. It still starts with a picture of what you have to start with.

Comment: I am with Zach need pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to restretch it if it is as smashed as you say. What you will need to do is cut out the bad part and insert a new length of fencing. You attach the new piece (splice) by taking one piece of wire from the fence and winding it through the existing fence and the new fence. This wire stitches the two pieces of fencing together.

Once you get the smashed portion replaced with good fencing you can restretch the whole length and attach it to the posts as normal.

pic from fence-material.com
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Yes I would just buy a new peace of fencing but if that cost too much you could hold it together with some cable ties.